# SQL Statement rows to Columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, rows

I have a Table in MS Access like this:

The Columns are:

```
--------------------------------------
| *Date* | *Article* | *Distance* | Value |
---------------------------------------
```

Date, Article and Distance are Primary Keys, so the combination of them is always unique.

The column Distance has discrete values from 0 to 27.

I need to transform this table into a table like this:

```
----------
| *Date* | *Article* | Value from Distance 0|  Value Dis. 1|...|Value Dis. 27|
----------
```

I really don't know a SQL Statement for this task. I needed a really fast solution which is why I wrote an Excel macro which worked fine but was very inefficient and needed several hours to complete. Now that the amount of data is 10 times higher, I can't use this macro anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following pivot query:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    Article,
    MAX(IIF(Distance = 0, Value, NULL)) AS val_0,
    MAX(IIF(Distance = 1, Value, NULL)) AS val_1,
    ...
    MAX(IIF(Distance = 27, Value, NULL)) AS val_27
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Date,
    Article
```

Note that Access does not support `CASE` expressions, but it does offer a function called `IIF()` which takes the form of:

```
IIF(condition, value if true, value if false)
```

which essentially behaves the same way as `CASE` in other RDBMS.